# Verifying MIME type on multiple uploaded files

Tags: php, mime-types

First of all I'd like to say that I am fairly new to PHP, and especially the go abouts on how to make a multiple upload script. And the problem I am encountering is how to validate the files with MIME types.

Based on my research - almost every source says to check the MIME type. I know this is because the $_FILE variables is user determined, and can cause bad files to be uploaded.

When I try to check the MIME type, I cannot get it to work. The script is supposed to only accept certain document files, and without the MIME check the script works fine. The problem is that it does not validate any file types, even if it is the ones I include in the array, and print the $errors variable.

This is the code:

```
foreach ($_FILES['ufile']['name'] as $f => $name) {

$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name']);
$ok = false;

switch ($mime) {
    case 'application/pdf':
        $ok = true;
        break;
    case 'application/msword':
        $ok = true;
        break;
    case 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document':
        $ok = true;
        break;
    default:
        $ok = false;
        break;
}

    if ($_FILES['ufile']['error'][$f] == 4) {
        continue;
    }          
    if ($_FILES['ufile']['error'][$f] == 0) {
        if ($_FILES['ufile']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
            $errors[] = 'message';
            continue;
        }
        elseif($ok == false){
            $errors[] = 'message';
            continue;
        }
        else{
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ufile"]["tmp_name"][$f], "path".$name))

            'queries and stuff.';
            }
    }
}
```

Any idea on what the problem might be? A new set of eyes might see something obvious that I should have seen or changed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: make sure your PHP version is 5.3+, as `FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE ` only available from 5.3

Comment: That example still uses the $_FILES variables, and making it insecure, or am I mistaken? @www.sblog.in

Comment: The PHP version is 5.3, and it should be available @kennypu

Comment: can you please explain how it is insecure ?

Comment: I am not claiming it is, but from what I have read and understand the $_FILES variables can be altered user-wise? @www.sblog.in

Comment: can you please send me the link

Comment: http://nullcandy.com/php-image-upload-security-how-not-to-do-it/ 
I had a couple of more, but I could not find them. I may have misunderstood what he wrote. @www.sblog.in

Comment: I have gone through it but can you avoid $_FILES variable, validation is a different part. validation depends on your particular requirements. whether a file is really an image or not that depends on your requirements.